# Why are my if elseif statemtnes being triggered when input entered is correct?

Tags: php, validation, if-statement

My if elseif statements are being triggered every time I hit submit and it is only specific ones. I have checked Stack for similar problems but they all have to do with statements not triggering. I have also tried to validate my form multiple times and no matter what, right or wrong, these specific ones are triggered:

Username: strlen statement
Password: strlen statement
E-Mail: FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
Empty Check is triggered even with all fields filled
Any help with correcting this would really be appreciated.

```
//Spam Check
if($spam > 2){
    $error .= '<div class="problem">Too many accounts have been created from this IP Address. Please contact us if you would like to create more.</div>';
}

//Username Check
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$user)){
    $error .= '<div class="problem">You may only use letters and numbers in your username.</div>';
}
elseif(strlen($user) < 3 OR strlen($user) > 20){
    $error .= '<div class="problem">Please use an username between 3 and 20 characters.</div>';
}
elseif($taken > 0){
    $error .= '<div class="problem">This username has already been taken. Please choose another.</div>';
}

//Password Check
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$pass1)){
        $error .= '<div class="problem">Do not use special characters in your password.</div>';
}
elseif(strlen($pass1) < 5 OR strlen($pass1) > 20){
    $error .= '<div class="problem">Your password must be at least 5 characters and no more than 20.</div>';
}
elseif($pass1 != $pass2){
    $error .= '<div class="problem">You did not confirm your passwords correctly. Please make sure they are the same.</div>';
}

//E-Mail Check
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error .= '<div class="problem">The E-Mail Address entered was invalid. Please use another.</div>';
}
elseif(strlen($email) > 50){
        $error .= '<div class="problem">This E-Mail Address is too large for us to store. Please use a different one.</div>';
}

//Empty Check
if(empty($user) OR empty($pass1) OR empty($pass2) OR empty($email)){
        $error .= '<div class="problem">You need to fill out all fields to create an account.</div>';
}
```

```
//Variables
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
$pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Comment: The `OR` operator is not interchangeable with `||` in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php They have different precedence, and can lead to _very different_ results. I haven't examined this closely enough to see if that's your problem, but you should definitely be using `||` in these conditions rather than `OR`.

Comment: Could you pass the inputs that you're using in your test? `var_dump($user,$pass1,$pass2,$email);`

Comment: Laxus - I have just ran the variables through var_dump and receiving null. I've add the form and variables to the question.

Comment: I wonder how you do not get a fatal error. `mysqli_real_escape_string` expects two parameters, and the first is the link identifier returned by `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: Yeah, your first parameter needs to be your mysqli_connection. If these variables are going to eventually be inserted into a database, you can use `$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);` or something similar.  Otherwise, you can sanitize your data in other ways (see my answer below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a mysqli function on POST data -- your variables aren't coming from SQL, are they?  Use trim() and strip_tags() or something similar to sanitize your data (but kudos for sanitizing to begin with, and using mysqli rather than mysql functions.)

Try something like this for all of your variables and see if your IF statements start evaluating correctly.  If they are all NULL, they are probably all returning false right now.

`$user = strip_tags(trim($_POST['username']));`

Comment: I kinda feel stupid now lol. I included my database connection file for sanitation and still forgot to add the first parameter. Thanks everyone for helping.